# getting error while trying to get "Grade" for StudentId=1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have below entities and database context class,

```
public class Grade
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } = new HashSet<Student>();
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}



public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=SchoolDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
}
```

Getting below error while executing below code, whats need to be done here. Thanks!

**I'm looking for solution without adding Grade property in Student class**

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Include property lambda expression 'x => {from Student c in x.Students where ([c].Id == __studentId_0) select [c]}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.'

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var studentId = 1;

        var context = new SchoolContext();
        var data = context.Grades.Include(x => x.Students.Where(c => c.Id == studentId)).SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `.SingleOrDefault()` is used for a sequence that contains only one element. Are sure that your sequence has only one member?

Comment: Yes, even `ToList()` giving same error

Comment: try it like this => `var data = context.Grades.Include(x => x.Students).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == studentId);`

Comment: @er-sho, `x => x.Id ` is the `id` for grade and NOT for `student`, I need to pass `StudentId`

Comment: Just select Student by id and include Grade (you should add navigation property Grade to Student class).

Comment: @user584018, there is no `GradeId` in student class but its in student table why? did u missed to add in class?

Comment: @er-sho, I'm using EF convention and `GradeId` column automatically generated for 'Student` table. Check `Grade` class

Comment: @Kirill Bestemyanov, as `Student` don't have `GradeId` property, even we select  `Student` by `id`, I can't be able to select right `Grade`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for solution without adding Grade property in Student class

So you want to be able to get the `Grade` for a `Student`, but don't want to add `Grade` navigation property to `Student` and let the EF Core handle naturally that for you? In other words, losing one of the biggest ORM benefits and start seeking for SQL-ish solutions for a simple requests which ORM can handle with a simple property accessor?

There are ways to do what you want, but I would suggest first asking yourself if you really need that.

Anyway, one possible solution is to use the collection navigation property with `Any` as filter:

```
var studentGrade = context.Grades
    .FirstOrDefault(grade => grade.Students.Any(student => student.Id == studentId));
```

Another is to use the LINQ equivalent of the SQL query:

```
var studentGrade = (
    from grade in context.Grades
    from student in grade.Students
    where student.Id == studentId
    select grade).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I understand that, but for my issue I can't change entity class... All I m using ODATA ef

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include navigation property by condition. Include can only contains lambda to navigation property without any conditions. To solve your problem you should add navigation property Grade to class Student and select from Students including Grade.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public Grade StudentGrade { get; set; }
}

…
var data = context.Students.Include(x => x.Grade).Where(c => c.Id == studentId).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I'm looking for solution without adding `Grade` property in `Student` class